# Can't install nvidia drivers on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

I'm having a heck of a time attempting to install drivers from nvidia into 17.3 linux mint. I can't use the ppa drivers because they won't work with CUDA which I need for tf for some reason.

Anyway when I attempt to install it after disabling X server it gives me

```
"The pre-install script for this distribution has failed!"
```

Moving passed that I continue and I choose to use the DKMS option because it sounds like less hassle but then it gives me

```
"Failed to run /usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 390.59 -k 4.98-040908-generic':
kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
Cleaning building area...
'make' -J8 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES-'' KERNEL_UNAME=4.9.8-040908-generic           modules....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status"
```

Then it fails and tells me not to use DKMS

When I do it without DKMS it throws another error

```
"CC version check failed"
```

and tells me something about the gcc versions between the installer and the one being used are different or something like that.

```
When I add CC=gcc-6.2 to the install command it fails again and says

"Unable to determine the version of the kernel sources located in 'lib/modules/(long name)'
```

So I add the supposed path the kernel source is supposed to be but it fails again. So I guess that wasn't right. I'm not really sure where the correct source to install is or if I'm going down the right path.

Now my linux install is messed up and whenever I try to login it crashes to fallback mode. Anyway to get this fixed and on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

open `etc/default/grub` and change
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash"`
Run 
`sudo update-grub2` then reboot your system run in low graphics when promoted

open 
`Driver Manager`
and install nvidia's driver
then run
`sudo nvidia-xconfig`
then restart your system.
Use this to see if your graphic card is working
`inxi -xG`